# MySQL Duplicate column error only when query wrapped as subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a select query like below:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.x = A.y
LEFT JOIN C ...
WHERE ....
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...;
```

All tables have `id` column and query works well. Result have many `id` columns without error and driver handles ambiguous issues. But i need to have LIMIT on results so i wrap it with another select query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM A
    LEFT JOIN B ON B.x = A.y
    LEFT JOIN C ...
    WHERE ....
    GROUP BY ...
    ORDER BY ...
) AS x WHERE 1 LIMIT 1000;
```

And now i get `Duplicate column name 'id'` error!

PS: The full query is complicated and i need to use `*` (listing column names is not possible), and i can't use limit in main query because of joins, group by order by and etc.

Comment: Why is column listing **impossible**?

Comment: well, you have to list all the column names and supply and alias for ambiguous columns.

Comment: Do you have any kind of grouping/having clause in your inner query? If not, why not just add `limit 1000` to your first query?

Comment: @juergend There are 50 JOINs and i have not all columns. I can handle ambiguous issues by database driver.

Comment: @MarkBannister Yes i have group by in inner query and that is why i'm using subquery.

Comment: People very rarely **need** to use `SELECT *`, and using it in production code is **never** a good idea, and in almost all cases is just laziness. I'm betting in the 42 minutes since you asked this question (with no answers as I comment) that you could have written out all the columns you need. The benefit of this is not just removing the duplicate column error, it also future proofs your column positions against DDL changes such as new columns being added, or columns being removed, it will also reduce I/O on the server and network traffic.

Comment: @GarethD It's not about laziness at all! The JOINs are all tables in database! so columns is list of all columns in all tables. Hardcoding columns list is a very bad idea and fetching list from information_schema is not ok for my case because of performance. Please note that it's not a normal query, It's a semi-report query. I used about 50 JOINs for performance and it works very well but limiting result.

Comment: I still don't see why you can't have a hard coded list, but ultimately, you will probably have to because you can't have duplicate column names in a subquery. What if you wanted to sort by `x.ID`, how would the db know which of the 50 columns called ID in `x` to sort by?

Comment: The only work around is to list the columns giving them usable aliases. If you can't use a prepared statement you could just copy the results of the following `SELECT CONCAT(TABLE_NAME, '.', COLUMN_NAME, ' AS `', TABLE_NAME, '.', COLUMN_NAME, '`,') FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` into your select list. Then update when the db changes, it is slightly more effort to maintain, but works, and means that your columns are uniquely identifiable.

Comment: :/ For each row of A, only one JOIN will be matched and all other columns are NULL. There is some info in A to find matched table (join) and driver can skip other columns well...

Comment: In all my years I've never come across a need to join 50 tables in a single query.

Comment: @gvee I'm fetching some data from all tables. It's like an export process. I can do it table by table absolutely but i'm doing like that to avoid many query executions. and FYI i have 90 tables but MySQL doesn't allow to have more than 60 joins ;)

Comment: @AHHP on your head be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it by self-join:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON B.x = A.y
LEFT JOIN C ...
JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM (
        SELECT id FROM A 
        WHERE ....
        GROUP BY ... 
        ORDER BY ...
    ) AS A1 WHERE 1 LIMIT 1000
) AS A2 ON A2.id = A.id
WHERE 1
```

MySQL executes it very fast.

Answer (score 10):

The reason you got the error is because of the aliasing `AS X`. But the problem really is that you used `*`, instead of listing the fields you want.

In the first query, the `SELECT *` actually produces fields such as:

```
A.id, A.name, A.description, B.id, B.name, B.date_started, C.id, C.name, C.isDeleted
```

This works fine, unless you try to reference a field by its name directly and don't use it's alias. Either way your SQL engine won't have a problem with this, whatever you are doing with the result set might still have a problem though.

However when you move your query into a subquery and alias the results `AS X`, then you end up with:

```
X.id, X.name, X.description, X.id, X.name, X.date_started, X.id, X.name, X.isDeleted
```

Now you can see why it's complaining.  You can see why it's also bad to use`*`, because this combination may work for some period of time, and then you add a new field to an existing table, that is the same as another table, and bang, every query you have written with both of these tables, now needs to be rewritten.