# Is this SQL statement valid, or is MySQL right to report an error?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, rdbms

I have a query with a subquery where the subquery alone runs correctly in MySQL, but the overall query produces an error. I've distilled the problem into a simplistic reproducable:

This is the query that produces an error in MySQL `ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'id'`

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT * FROM locations l
       RIGHT JOIN total_cases c
               ON l.id=c.loc_id) a;
```

Running just the subquery,

```
SELECT * FROM locations l
   RIGHT JOIN total_cases c
           ON l.id=c.loc_id;
```

produces results

```
+------+----------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+
| id   | location       | id   | loc_id | date       | total_cases |
+------+----------------+------+--------+------------+-------------+
|  237 | United Kingdom |    1 |    237 | 2020-05-09 |      203171 |
|  237 | United Kingdom |    2 |    237 | 2020-05-10 |      206234 |
|  237 | United Kingdom |    3 |    237 | 2020-05-11 |      208391 |
...
```

I am interested from the RDBMS perspective. Is a duplicate `id` column valid as the result of a join, but not valid in the column list of a `SELECT` statement? If anyone can provide a standard reference, too, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT**: downvotes and answers about how to reconstruct the query suggest my question is not clear. I want to understand *from the perspective of the RDBMS* what the correct behaviour is, and the difference between duplicate columns in the subquery and the outer query. This is a database question, not a 'how to write my sql' question. Thanks!

Comment: *Is a duplicate id column valid as the result of a join* No. MySQL extension allows this in output list (ambiguity is client's problem which needs to refer to such columns by their posession index). But such ambiguity in subquery output is MySQL problem which have no posession reference - so it generates an error.

Comment: Yes, most RDBMS will produce a similar error as the column names are not distinct. Eg MS SQL Server gives "error The column 'Id' was specified multiple times for 'a'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Duplicate column error only when query wrapped as subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19681650/mysql-duplicate-column-error-only-when-query-wrapped-as-subquery)

Comment: @Akina a MySQL extension. Ok, so the subquery *should* also error in a Standard-conforming database?

Comment: *so the subquery should also error in a Standard-conforming database?* True

Comment: @Akina Thanks! If you could create an answer, I'll accept it as solved. Can you give me any references?

Answer (score 1):

The subquery returns two columns with the exact same name, `id`. When you are trying to select from that as a subquery it does not know which id it needs to refer to. You need to state the column names in your subquery and make sure there is no duplicate column names.

Comment: thanks, but the question is about the validity of duplicate columns in a subquery

Comment: Actually, this does answer about the validity. It's works in one query because it's simply outputting all columns, but in your nested query it is outputting to another query which requires unique column names.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html says

*A derived table is an expression that generates a table within the scope of a query FROM clause. For example, a subquery in a SELECT statement FROM clause is a derived table*

then it says

*Any columns in the derived table must have unique names*

Comment: This is the correct answer. We all know there is a duplicate column. This says why it works in one context but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

id is in both tables, so you now can decide

IF you need all columns

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT l.*,c.* FROM locations l
       RIGHT JOIN total_cases c
               ON l.id=c.loc_id) a;
```

Or if you don't want the dupes from bith tables

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
    SELECT l.location ,c.* FROM locations l
       RIGHT JOIN total_cases c
               ON l.id=c.loc_id) a;
```

Mysql can't decide for you which you want and need, so you have to tell him that.

The subquery alone with his SELECT * only as result set, but when you try to use is as basis for an OUT Query, it becomes a temporary table, which has certain rukes and one of them that every column has to have its own name, to be identifies correctly

Comment: thanks, but the question is about the validity of duplicate columns in a subquery

Answer (score 0):

Use alias in your inner query so that you don't have two columns with same name `id` in the outer query.

The inner query is lenient, it assumes you are doing a test

The outer query executes the inner query. and while executing, it finds two column with same `column_name`

Let me illustrate with an example.

> assume you have a school and the school has two classrooms labeled
> with the same name. like `class 4A` and `class 4A` . That is not a
> problem up to that point . the problem comes in when you want to send
> a student to go and visit `class 4A` . the student will come back with
> an error . "which `class 4A` are you talking about sir?"
>
> Building and labelling the class no problem, but when executing problems

```
SELECT a.* FROM (    SELECT      
 l.id as location_id,
 l.location,
 c.id as case_id,
 c.loc_id,
 c.date,
 c.total_cases FROM locations l
RIGHT JOIN total_cases c
       ON l.id=c.loc_id) a;
```

Comment: this is right, but you're not explaining about why one is valid and the subquery is not. You could be a little more clear on that.

Comment: Sure . let me add more meat